# Joining equal values that were returned from a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, zend-framework2

I'm using a database in MySQL and returning values ​​via PHP. I'm using the framework Zend2.

I have the following table:

```
[ID] | [Name] | [Amount]
-----|--------|---------
1    | Alex   | 10
-----|--------|---------
2    | Bruno  | 5
-----|--------|---------
3    | Miguel | 6
-----|--------|---------
4    | Ana    | 5
```

I need to unite draws. In this case, instead of displaying

[image]

the result should display

[image]

Code to show in HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($row->amount); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($row->name); ?></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo $row->imageMedal($i); ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The Zend2 structure has not changed.

Comment: you need a query or what?)

Answer (score 3):

You can `GROUP_BY` amount and concatenate `Name` in the groups with the same `amount`, then you can order by `amount` from the greatest value and cut the first three rows :

```
SELECT `amount`
     , GROUP_CONCAT(`Name` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `name`
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY `amount` 
ORDER BY `amount` DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: Seems to solve the problem. Now I'm looking for how to create this query in Zend2.

Comment: @KeplerBR : Have you succeeded?

Comment: I'm having difficulty in implementing this in Zend2. My current code: http://pastebin.com/pHW8RE90

Comment: @KeplerBR : I'd like to help you, but I am not familiar with this framework)

Answer (score 0):

@KeplerBR, here's a solution in ZF2 for your query: https://gist.github.com/settermjd/3360ccabb2b761a6ee11